# How to simplify Time Complexity equation?

Tags: algorithm, math, algebra

So the past few days I've been trying to learn algorithms analysis but hasn't been a good time. I stumbled on [this stackexchange question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97901/answering-questions-about-the-recurrence-of-certain-aspects-of-an-algorithm) because it was pretty similar to my question. The only problem is that I got stuck with the current accepted answer.

The accepted answer states:
[Equation Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MACBn.png)

My question is: How does he simplify the 1st equation to get the `T(n) = 3/2 * T(n-1) + 1` ?

Comment: Multiply through by 3/2, should be +3/2 instead of +1 in the second equation.

Comment: @ml2017 please see the answer instead of question ... the person who answered his/her question mentioned that it should be 3/2*(T(n-1) +1)